# How to plot histogram axis in a marginal plot in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I have created a series of marginal plots looking at two variables using ggMarginal and ggplot2. However, I want to include an axis on the histogram that has the scale so I know roughly how many values fall into each bin.

I have already checked the documentation for ggMarginal and am at a loss.

Comment: Relevant: [Adding axis to marginal denstity plot and histograms](https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/59)

Comment: To expand above comment; from the `ggExtra` developers: *"[...] this kind of customization is out of scope for the package"*; so no, I don't think there is a straightforward out-of-the-box solution based on `ggMarginal`. There exist a few posts here on SO that demonstrate how to add custom marginal `ggplot`s  (e.g. using `cowplot`), which may give you more flexibility regarding customising the marginal plots.